# Auto-load a module on python startup

Tags: python, module, autoload, ipython

I want IPython or the Python interpreter to auto-load a module when I start them.

Is it possible?

For example when I start IPython:

```
$ ipython

...

>>> from __future__ import division
>>> from mymodule import *

In [1]:
```

Something like [SymPy's live shell](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/index.html#tutorial) found in the tutorial pages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the file `~/.ipython/ipythonrc` - you can list all modules you want to load at the startup.

Comment: Note that iPython has since deprecated `ipythonrc`. The new configuration file has the same functionality (and much more), as described [in their documentation](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/config/ipython.html#example).

Comment: That link is dead now. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20835977/ for a resolution.

Answer (score 18):

Have a `.pythonstartup` in your home directory and load modules there and point `PYTHONSTARTUP` env to that file.

Python commands in that file are executed before the first prompt is displayed in interactive mode.

- http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html

I use it for enabling command line completion in python interpreter shell

Comment: Thank you too! But now how can I choose two accepted answer??

Comment: @rubik: @eumiro: eumiro answered first and his answer is unique and my answer works too. Accept eumiro's answer.

Answer (score 7):

Unless `-S` option is passed to the `python` binary, a special [site](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/site.html) module is imported by default before the execution is passed to your script, or the interactive interpreter. Among other things the module looks for `*.pth` files. On each line the `*.pth` files should contain either a path to include into `sys.path`, or a command to execute. The module as well imports `sitecustomize`, and `usercustomize` (which can contain arbitrary code, a good way to make your colleagues crazy, if they happen to raise errors) if they exist somewhere in `sys.path`.

The problem is though, that the current directory in not in `sys.path` when the `site` module is imported, that is it is hard to configure your particular script.

I sometimes add the following line at the beginning of my scripts, so that the script would start with searchin for `.pth` files in the current directory and adding the missing paths to `sys.path`:

```
# search for *.pth files in the current directory
import site; site.addsitedir('')
```

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution is to use [the argument `-i` from `python` interpreter](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-i) that launches the interaction mode after executing your script.

You could for instance use:

- `python -i your_module.py`
- `python -i /path/to/your/module` in case you have defined a `__main__.py`
- or even `python -i -m your.module`

Answer (score 1):

To automatically lazily import all top-level importable modules when using them, define this in your `PYTHONSTARTUP` file:

```
import pkgutil
from importlib import import_module

class LazyModule:
    def __init__(self, alias, path):
        self._alias = alias
        self._path = path
        globals()[self._alias] = self

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        module = import_module(self._path)
        globals()[self._alias] = module
        return getattr(module, attr)

# All top-level modules.
modules = [x.name for x in pkgutil.iter_modules()]

for module in modules:
    LazyModule(alias=module, path=module)

# Also include any other custom aliases.
LazyModule("mpl", "matplotlib")
LazyModule("plt", "matplotlib.pyplot")
LazyModule("pd", "pandas")
LazyModule("sns", "seaborn")
LazyModule("tf", "tensorflow")
```

Now you can access modules without needing to import them manually:

```
>>> math.sqrt(0)
0
```