# Auto-Loading a module on IPython startup

Tags: python, python-2.7, module, ipython, startup

I'm trying to to auto load the `division` module from `__future__` on startup,
i've currently got a simple script in the IPython startup libray with the line:

```
from __future__ import division
```

which works fine when run directly from the shell,
however, the module does not appear to load when the line is run from the script,
i made sure that the startup script is loaded by adding some arbitrary variable assignments to it:

```
from __future__import division
x=1
y=2
```

and the variables were preassigned when IPython was launched (as expected).

I've tried looking at some solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002924/auto-load-a-module-on-python-startup) and [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&sqi=2&ved=0CDQQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F11124578%2Fautomatically-import-modules-when-entering-the-python-or-ipython-interpreter&ei=PCzBUqC-Coa47Qa5y4EQ&usg=AFQjCNHCXGT6hQTZZ6aXt_WytbaSoOFWJQ&sig2=6G5bj8ILd_ndj2I9vKfaDg&cad=rja) but got nowhere,
any help would be appreciated,
thanks

Comment: Please remove the solution from the question and post it as an answer below and accept it.

Comment: Note that the problem is that putting the `__future__` call inside a script you are activating the feature *in that script*, not at a "global level" in the interpreter.

Comment: what consequences would that have?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11124578/860421

Answer (score 11, accepted):

i've found a solution to this one, in your IPython profile directory (by default - `.ipython\profile_default`), edit the file `ipython_config.py` (create it with `ipython profile create` if it does not exist) with the following lines:

```
# loads the root config object
c=get_config()

# executes the line in brackets on program launch
c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines = ['from __future__ import division']
```