# IPython startup customization

Tags: ipython

I am trying to load things like `from __future__ import division` on the `IPython` startup on windows 7 64 bit machine, `python 2.7 64 bit`.

I searched the web and the recommended way I found is to put a `.py` file with instructions in: `C:\Users\Me\.ipython\profile_default\startup`. I've put a simple `.py` file containing

```
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import unicode_literals
```

in that folder. But it actually does nothing. What is more confusing is that the file seems to execute, because if I put some random error line in there, i see an error on Ipython start. Still division is not imported and have to re-import it typing `from __future__ import division` in the shell.

I tried it both on `Anaconda` and `Winpython`(settings for `IPython` on this distribution are in other folder) with the same result. After I re-import everything works fine. Totally stuck here, please help!

Comment: The solution which is posted here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20835977/auto-loading-a-module-from-future-on-ipython-startup?rq=1) produces and error.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Check to see if `C:\Users\Me\.ipython\profile_default\ipython_config.py` exists. If it doesn't, run

```
ipython profile create
```

from the command line to generate it. Next, open it in your favorite text editor and search for `c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines`. Uncomment that line (it's line 27 in my file) and edit it to be the following:

```py
c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines = ["from __future__ import division", "from __future__ import unicode_literals"]
```

Save the file, restart IPython, and you should be all set.

Comment: Now I just need django's shell_plus to respect this, and we're all set!

Comment: note: `get_ipython()` returns `None` in `ipython_config.py`. Create `*.py` files in the `startup` dir if you need access to `ipython` itself (e.g., [to define formatters](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/integrating.html#formatters-for-third-party-types))