# How to run project files using Anaconda from any directory in Windows

Tags: python, anaconda

Python newbie here. Am using Anaconda (on Windows 7) by recommendation of a friend.

What I want to be able to do is make a change to my class in Notepad++ and then test it in my Python command prompt window immediately.

This is a simple question that I can't seem to find the answer: in what directory does a default installation of Anaconda expect me to be storing my .py files (so that I can easily load them using `import <MODULE NAME>`)?

My PATH variable is set to:
`C:\USERS\<USERNAME>\Anaconda3;C:\USERS\<USERNAME>\Anaconda3\Scripts`

(this is the default)

Am I supposed to be working out of the `Scripts` directory...? There's already a lot of files in there.

What do most people do? Perhaps add another folder to the PATH variable and work out of there? Do you add a new folder to PATH for each project or is there a way that makes more sense? I already have a Projects directory I use for everything else. I'd like to just be able to work out of there.

I am coding in Notepad++. I don't really want to bother setting up/learning an IDE (I'm just doing relatively simple I/O file manipulation that I have previously been doing in Excel... the horror).

Sorry for the extremely newbie question. I searched and could not find anything relevant.

EDIT AFTER ACCEPTED ANSWER:

The problem was that I was running python.exe from the Start menu. I did not realize that you are supposed to open a CMD window in the folder (SHIFT+RIGHT CLICK) you are working in (such as `C:\USERS\<USERNAME>\MY PYTHON STUFF`) and run python from there.

Comment: I would recommend against this because it's a fairly advanced issue, but if you really want to do it... [link](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html). Otherwise, just keep to working inside your folder. The "custom" modules I use just reside in a generic folder that handles my snippets and I copy them to my project folders if needed. Saves me the hassle of having to deal with the `import` system (which I don't really need to mess around with).

Comment: How do I "work inside my folder"? I am coding in Notepad++. I don't really want to bother setting up/learning an IDE (I'm just doing relatively simple I/O file manipulation that I have previously been doing in Excel... the horror). I want to make a change to my class in Notepad++ and then test it in my Python command prompt window.

Comment: You're skipping an awful lot of tutorials for a beginner. Just save the `.py` file *anywhere*, go to that directory from the terminal, then use `python <name of file>.py`. Another option is to just double-click the file if it's supposed to run right away without any arguments.

Comment: Thanks, I already know how to do that but the problem is my file defines a class. It doesn't do anything. I want to create an object and use its methods to test it without writing testing procedures inside the module that I have to clean up later.

Comment: What I want to do is simply run python.exe and use my class there, easily, the same as I would `Input: x = 1` and `Input: x` then `Output: 1`. But it's beginning to seem like that isn't a simple thing to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might be what you're attempting. Note that I also use Anaconda.

**My path:**

```
C:\Users\...\Documents\Python Scripts\
```

**import_sample.py**

```
class class_sample(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.x = ["I", "am", "doing", "something", "with", "Python"]
```

**test.py**

```
from import_sample import class_sample

c = class_sample()
y = c.x
print " ".join(y)
```

**Result:**

```
I am doing something with Python
[Finished in 0.1s]
```

Notice how being in the same folder allows me to import without having to *install*, per se. Basically, just make sure that the modules you need are in the same folder as your `main.py` and you're good.

**EDIT:**

Done from the terminal.

[image]

Notice how I `cd` into the above folder and activated `python` there. Since I was inside that folder, any modules inside it can be imported without any problems, alongside other system-wide modules installed as well.

Comment: Is there a way to do this from the python command window and skip the test.py step? I want to just be able to quickly create an object and test a method I just wrote by typing the lines `import mymodule`, `myobject = mymodule.myclass()`, `myobject.mymethod()` and then getting some output in the same window.

Comment: Go into your folder containing the module, type `python`, and `import` from there. Don't run `python.exe`, that's defeating the purpose of Python being on the path. You're perfectly allowed to do it from virtually any folder. I'll be editing my answer with an example.

Comment: Ahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh. I see! I knew it would be a simple answer. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help. I love Anaconda to bits and pieces and it's always nice to help out someone using the distro. Enjoy!

Comment: I just realized that you spend an awful lot of time with Excel, similar to myself. If that is so, I sincerely recommend the `pandas` library. Since you're using Anaconda, it's supposed to be installed right away. It's far and wide much better to use Pandas than VBA.

Comment: Thanks again. I've already discovered xlwings but I'll give pandas a look as well.

Comment: It's also worth looking at the IPython notebook (also comes with Anaconda).

Comment: I use anaconda too on a win7 system. Can you give me a tip about how to access common modules which I develop myself? 
I'd like to store the common modules on a dropbox folder, which will be in a separate folder to the other python modules that call them. I have tried placing a path reference to the common module folder in the PATH environmental variable, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @dreme See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4002933/2437514). Read about the [PYTHONSTARTUP](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONSTARTUP) variable and point it to a file that imports the modules you want when Python starts.