# Where is the Ananconda launcher in Windows 8?

Tags: python, anaconda

I am complete Python newb here who is just making the switch from MATLAB. I installed the `Anaconda 2.4` with `Python 2.7` on a `64-bit` Windows 8.1 system. But I cannot even start the program as I cannot find any Anaconda launcher either on the Start menu or the desktop. Any help please?

Comment: Search your whole computer? Mine is in Users/'MyUserFolder'/AppData/Local/Continuum. You can also look for 'Spyder' which is Anaconda's python editor. But I have shortcuts automatically added in the start menu in 'All Programs/Anaconda'.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [docs](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda-launcher/):

> As of Anaconda 4.0, Anaconda Launcher has been replaced by Anaconda Navigator.

So you should upgrade Anaconda versions and use Navigator instead of Launcher if you want to use the GUI to launch something like Spyder. (You may know about this change already since you asked this a long time ago.)

If you can't find Navigator in the programs menu or Desktop, you can do `anaconda-navigator` in cmd. Here's more [info.](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/navigator.html) about it. You can also do `spyder` in cmd to launch Spyder.

Comment: what if i didn't add anaconda folder to the path?

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer suggesting upgrading to Anaconda 4.0+ is probably sensible. However if this is not a desirable option, the below will allow use of Anaconda Launcher on previous versions.

Anaconda is installed under 'C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Anaconda'.

The Anaconda Launcher can be open by clicking on the Start menu and typing `Run` (or hit `Windows+r`) and entering `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Anaconda\Scripts\launcher.bat` and clicking OK. Alternatively you can navigate to 'C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Anaconda\Scripts' in a command-prompt and enter `launcher.bat`.

You stated in a comment on another answer that you were "actually looking to open spyder". You can do this with `Windows+r` `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Anaconda\Scripts\spyder.exe` or by navigating to 'C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Anaconda\Scripts' in a command-prompt and typing `python spyder-script.py`.

If you're only ever after spyder, a taskbar shortcut with a pretty icon is always nice. To do this, go to 'C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Anaconda\Scripts' in an Explorer window and drag `spyder.exe` to the taskbar, then if you right-click this and goto `Properties` then `Change Icon...` you can add the icon from 'C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Anaconda\Scripts\spyder.ico'.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

From a quick google search, it appears to be a web hosted app & not something  you just click on in the startmenu.

http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/launcher

Comment: this is likely not what OP is asking for.

Comment: I unfortunately can't post comments because i don't have the rep to or i would have don't just that.  :/

Answer (score 0):

Feel your pain. Simple getting started questions like this were hard to figure out at first for me, too.

I am assuming what you actually want to do is launch Python. You have a few choices.

- Searching for `python` in the Start menu and hitting `Enter`
- Open a command window (search for `cmd` in the Start menu and hit `Enter`). Type `python` and hit `Enter`.
- Shift-right click inside any specific directory in which you want to open python, and click launch command window. Type python and hit enter.

Also have a look at [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26488981/how-to-run-project-files-using-anaconda-from-any-directory-in-windows) from about a year ago; you should find the accepted answer helpful.

Comment: Yes, I was able to launch Python ultimately through the command line, and update through conda too. But I was actually looking to open spyder - which so far eludes me

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced same issue. I was unable to see Anaconda launcher or prompt in the start menu. But for me a simple thing solved this!

First I actually installed anaconda with 'Anaconda3-2022.05-Windows-x86_64' exe file, where I faced this problems.

**Solution:**

I uninstalled latest version of anaconda. Then, I just installed an earlier version of anaconda 'Anaconda3-2021.05-Windows-x86_64', which I downloaded from 'https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/'.

This solved issue in my case.